# Multiply array elements

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, multiplication

So I'm learning bash and need to do a simple script to multiply array elements by calling a function.

My code so far is this, but it ain't working at all. I believe there is a much simpler way than this (incrementing the `pos` variable so as to move to the next array element feels simply wrong).

```
array=(1 2 3 4 5 100)
sum=0
pos=1


function multiplicate {
        for i in ${array[*]};do
                sum=$(($i * $array[pos]))
                let pos++ 
        done
}

multiplicate

echo $sum
```

I did my best to google the solution but was unable to find any relevant information, I found how to sum by using bc, but it simply wouldn't work by replacing `+` with `*`.

Comment: You're just replacing `sum` each time, you're not combining the new value with the previous one.

Comment: Why are you not up voting any answer in any of all your past questions and also not selecting any answer. That is considered being rude.

Comment: Alejo, you now have 5 questions on this site and none have been accepted with a Green Check Mark. That's how we roll here. Please see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234)

Comment: Understood Sir, I apologize. Will correct that in a few!

Answer (score 2):

Use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=(1 2 3 4 5 100)

function multiplicate {
    local mul=1
    for i in "${array[@]}"; do
        ((mul *= i))
    done
    echo "$mul"
}

multiplicate


$ ./script
12000
```

Or better yet:

```
#!/bin/bash

multiplicate() {
    local  mul=1
    for    i
    do     ((mul *= i))
    done
    echo   "$mul"
}

multiplicate 1 2 3 4 5 100
```

And if you like to play with string variables use this:

```
multiplicate() { local IFS=* ; echo $(( $* )); }

multiplicate 1 2 3 4 5 100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! For some reason I tend to overcomplicate things, seeing your code makes it much more easier now!

Comment: @Alejo Please accept it if it solved you question. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks for helping him. Plus uno.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method using `bc`:

```
multiply ()
{
    printf '%s\n' "$@" | paste -s -d '*' | bc
}
```

Used as follows:

```
$ multiply 1 2 3 4 5 100
12000
```

The first command in the pipeline prints each array elements on a separate line:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 1 2 3 4 5 100
1
2
3
4
5
100
```

The `paste -s` ("serial") then turns the output into a single line again, but the elements now separated by `*`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 1 2 3 4 5 100 | paste -s -d '*'
1*2*3*4*5*100
```

And `bc` finally evaluates the expression.

Alternatively, we can save a subshell and skip `bc`:

```
multiply () {
    echo $(( $(printf '%s\n' "$@" | paste -s -d '*') ))
}
```

This uses an arithmetic expression to evaluate the output of `printf` and `paste` (which now is in a command substitution), but readability suffers a bit.

Alternatively, in pure Bash (hat tip [sorontar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6843677/sorontar)):

```
multiply () {
    local IFS='*'
    echo "$(( $* ))"
}
```

This sets the field separator `IFS` to `*` so the arguments, `$*`, expand to a string separated by `*`, which is then evaluated in the arithmetic expression `$(())`.

Comment: No need to call paste (an slow call to an external utility), just define the main program function as: `multiply() { local IFS=* ; echo "$(( $* ))"; }`

Comment: @sorontar Ah, neat! I'll add that.

Comment: Thanks for helping him. Plus uno.

Comment: like the pure `bash` approach, `+1`